# Prove by induction $g(n) = 5^{2n} - 6n + 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

a) show that $g(k+1) = 25g(k) + 9(16k-22)$
b) Hence, or otherwise, prove by induction $g(n)$ is divisble by 9.

Completely lost here with the manipulation, I can't seem to achieve $9(16k-22)$

Solution also gives $25(5^{2k} - 6k + 8) + 144k -198$ I can't seem to understand how they've arrived to this.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(n)=5^{2n}-6n+8=25^n-6n+8$$
$$\begin{align}
g(n+1)
&=25^{n+1}-6(n+1)+8\\
&=25(25^n)-6n+2\\
&=25(25^n-6n+8)+9(16n-22)\\
&=g(n)+9(16n-22)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: No, $g(n)=5^2n-6n+8=25n-6n+8$. Ah, sorry, the OP changes again the formula.

Comment: Ramanujan is baaaack!